# What is this graphic art style called?

Tags: style-identification, style

There is this type of graphic art that involves using only parts of the picture to trick me as if I am seeing the whole picture.

For example, you might include a few stripes and an eye, all placed where they should anatomically be, as a means of conveying a tiger.

#### Examples

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Comment: @AndrewH excellent, I found some examples - http://www.ateneupopular.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/negative_space_animal_05.jpg and https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/86/d3/33/86d3335691a512158574d2bd536b1f5b.jpg

Comment: @AndrewH in the first one, the man atop the horse is a perfect example of the type of optical illusion I'm talking about, but both are good examples of the technique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no name for the style you're referring to that I'm aware of. Its just using [Gestalt Principle of Closure](https://www.google.com/search?q=logo%20gestalt%20closure&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj17Lyr9ubMAhXKWx4KHbb-ADkQ_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=1009) which can be read about in all sorts of places such as [Creative Bloq: Gestalt Theory](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/gestalt-theory-10134960).

The most iconic probably being the World Wildlife Foundation Panda

[image]

We also have a number of questions on the topic: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=gestalt

Answer (score 2):

These are examples of negative space designs.

Comment: No, they're not.